# TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid

Tags: solidity

When checking if the number of tokens is greater or equal to in the smart contract it self it gives me this error;

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid
```

See code below:

```
contract MarbCoinSale {

    address admin;

    MarbCoin public tokenContract;

    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    constructor (MarbCoin _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }

    function multiply(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
    }

    function buyTokens (uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {

        require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));

        require(tokenContract.balanceOf(this) >= _numberOfTokens);

        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;

        emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know the balance of an ERC20 token? or the ETH balance?

Comment: I want to know the balance of an ERC20 token